# Is changing lip colour haram?

Tags: halal-haram

I've heard from sources that you can change somethings about yourself for temporarily or it has to be a slight adjustment so does changing lip colour apply to these.

Answer (score 1):

## It depends.

If you were to go out to (public) places where non-Mahram would see you, then it is Haram to put anything on your lips that would change their natural color or any kind of makeup except those used for **lightening** the skin without harming or damaging it (again **lightening** and not **changing** its original color). It is Haram since makeup makes women look younger and prettier.

On the other hand, it is permitted if you were in a place (such as your house) where only Mahram (like your husband, father, uncle..etc) and women there, with taking into consideration that it is temporary and can be removed (not like facial cosmetic surgeries for example, which are Haram).

It is stated in [Surah Al-Nur (24) — Verse 31](https://quran.com/24/31):

In Arabic (the exact wording):

> وَقُل لِّلْمُؤْمِنَاتِ يَغْضُضْنَ مِنْ أَبْصَارِهِنَّ وَيَحْفَظْنَ فُرُوجَهُنَّ وَلا يُبْدِينَ زِينَتَهُنَّ إِلاَّ مَا ظَهَرَ مِنْهَا وَلْيَضْرِبْنَ بِخُمُرِهِنَّ عَلَى جُيُوبِهِنَّ وَلا يُبْدِينَ زِينَتَهُنَّ إِلاَّ لِبُعُولَتِهِنَّ أَوْ آبَائِهِنَّ أَوْ آبَاء بُعُولَتِهِنَّ أَوْ أَبْنَائِهِنَّ أَوْ أَبْنَاء بُعُولَتِهِنَّ أَوْ إِخْوَانِهِنَّ أَوْ بَنِي إِخْوَانِهِنَّ أَوْ بَنِي أَخَوَاتِهِنَّ أَوْ نِسَائِهِنَّ أَوْ مَا مَلَكَتْ أَيْمَانُهُنَّ أَوِ التَّابِعِينَ غَيْرِ أُولِي الإِرْبَةِ مِنَ الرِّجَالِ أَوِ الطِّفْلِ الَّذِينَ لَمْ يَظْهَرُوا عَلَى عَوْرَاتِ النِّسَاء وَلا يَضْرِبْنَ بِأَرْجُلِهِنَّ لِيُعْلَمَ مَا يُخْفِينَ مِن زِينَتِهِنَّ وَتُوبُوا إِلَى اللَّهِ جَمِيعًا أَيُّهَا الْمُؤْمِنُونَ لَعَلَّكُمْ تُفْلِحُونَ

In English (in what it means):

> And tell the believing women to reduce [some] of their vision and guard their private parts and not expose their adornment except that which [necessarily] appears thereof and to wrap [a portion of] their headcovers over their chests and not expose their adornment except to their husbands, their fathers, their husbands' fathers, their sons, their husbands' sons, their brothers, their brothers' sons, their sisters' sons, their women, that which their right hands possess, or those male attendants having no physical desire, or children who are not yet aware of the private aspects of women. And let them not stamp their feet to make known what they conceal of their adornment. And turn to Allah in repentance, all of you, O believers, that you might succeed.

[Source — a website in Arabic](https://binbaz.org.sa/fatwas/17405/%D9%85%D8%A7-%D8%AD%D9%83%D9%85-%D8%A7%D8%B3%D8%AA%D8%B9%D9%85%D8%A7%D9%84-%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%85%D8%B1%D8%A7%D8%A9-%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%85%D9%83%D9%8A%D8%A7%D8%AC)